# Using jQuery take 2 IDs and display custom content

Tags: jquery, html, image, click

I'm new to jQuery and I know this question might seem dumb. But, here is what I have so far... http://jsfiddle.net/jHyJu/

```
$('[id^=content]').hide();
$('#baseSection').delegate("li", "click", function() {
var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('bcontent','');
$("#baseContent").html($("#content-"+id).html());
});

$('[id^=content]').hide();
$('#headSection').delegate("li", "click", function() {
var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('hcontent','');
$("#headContent").html($("#content-"+id).html());
});
```

I need the script to combine the clicked ids so I can display custom content.

Comment: Do you have any questions? `<li  id="hcontent5">5</a></li>` Where is the opening `<a>`?

Comment: That was apart of the original code and thought I had removed all <a> references. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Yeah I do have a question would you know how I can change what I have to get id + id = content? example I click base 1 + head 1 = content 1 or I click base 1 + head 2 = content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of `ternary operator`: <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/jHyJu/1/</kbd>

```
    $('[id^=content]').hide();
    $('#baseSection, #headSection').on("click", "li", function () {
        var id = ($(this).parent().attr('id') == 'selectable') ? $(this).attr('id').replace('bcontent', '') : $(this).attr('id').replace('hcontent', '');
        $("#baseContent").html($("#content-" + id).html());
    });
```

and use `.on()` instead `if you are using jquery version 1.7+`

Comment: This worked. Thank you! Is their a way I can get id + id = content? example I click base 1 + head 1 = content 1 or I click base 1 + head 2 = content 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('[id^=content]').hide();
    $('#baseSection, #headSection').delegate("li", "click", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('bcontent','').replace('hcontent','');
    $("#baseContent, #headContent").html($("#content-"+id).html());
    });
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
   $('#baseSection, #headSection').delegate
```

and keep all the code same except for the following lines

```
var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('hcontent','');
var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('bcontent','');
```

here you can have 'hcontent/bcontent' as element's attribute and can use it using

```
$(this).attr('<attribute name>')
```

and use as varibale